# Select div's ids that has specific class

Tags: jquery, html

I have something very similar to this

```
<div id="bigBadDiv">
<div class="head">
    blabla
</div>

<div class="contents">
    <div class="1">
        <div id="432" class="item "></div>
        <div id="45" class="item selected"></div>
        <div id="86" class="item "></div>
        <div id="3" class="item "></div>
    </div>

    <div class="2">
        <div id="443" class="item"></div>
        <div id="867" class="item selected"></div>
        <div id="43" class="item selected"></div>
        <div id="98" class="item selected"></div>
    </div>


    <div class="3">
        <div id="423" class="item selected"></div>
        <div id="167" class="item "></div>
        <div id="4453" class="item "></div>
        <div id="944" class="item "></div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="footer">
    blabla
</div>
```

I want to select id's only of **.selected** items and I try to make it with

```
 $('#bigBadDiv :has(.selected)').css({'backgroundColor':'red'});
```

but it turns the **.contents** background to red...
Do you know why is that happening ?
Can you help me select every div.selected and take its id valu?  Maybe with some kind of loop .. ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the selector, just leave [`:has()`](http://api.jquery.com/has-selector/) wrapper.  For the ID part, you can get an array of ids using [`.map()`](http://api.jquery.com/map/), like this:

```
var ids = $('#bigBadDiv .selected').map(function() { return this.id; }).get();
```

[You can test it out here](http://www.jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/VGz4f/1/).

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#bigBadDiv .selected').css({'backgroundColor':'red'});
```

Answer (score 0):

if you use the standards conform

```
selected="selected"
```

you can query the result by

```
$('*.div').attr('selected')? Do something if : do something if not;
```